# How to say tehilims for someone else

Tags: tefilla, minhag, sources-mekorot, prayer-book, tehilim-psalms

I have a friend of mine, just before a big challenge. I would like to pray for her somehow. How to do that and what exact tehilims should i say?

Comment: In general, with prayer, the main thing is the intent. It is perfectly acceptable to pray in your own words.

Comment: Are you specifically looking for ways to incorporate Tehillim into your prayer? Or just any way of praying?

Comment: Big challenge - as in, medically? Or otherwise? As others have noted, the main thing is intent, and feel free to just open your heart to HaShem and plead that he answers, but if you're looking for the specific prayers brought down, that could vary depending on the challenge.

Answer (score 1):

I have been told by my rabbeim in Atlanta and Passaic to either

1. read the entire *Sefer Tehillim* cover to cover, yourself or dividing it among a group; or
2. pick a set of psalms with resonating themes (ones usually used are 121 and 130, sometimes 20, 23, and many others);

and say them yourself repeatedly, thinking over them carefully as you say them, and have your person in mind among other ill people of Israel. If you say in a minyan responsively, it is common to also add a *mishebeirach*, a special prayer for the welfare after saying them, either in their merit or in the merit of you giving *tzedaka* for the speedy recovery.

Let it be His will to bless your friend with a speedy recovery soon.

Comment: OP mentioned "big challenge" and you are giving instructions for a "speedy recovery"....

Comment: If you say it in a Minyan then Kaddish would be said after like any public recitation of verses

Comment: @DannySchoemann one always hopes and prays for speedy recovery -- how it happens is up to Him...

Comment: That just seemed more important than the misheberach...

Comment: @DoubleAA likely more meritorious as well -- would you like me to update the answer?

Answer (score -1):

You can always say the "Tikun Ha'klaly" - a collective of 10 tehilim chapters Rabbi Nachman recommended saying as a 'tikun'.

The chapters are:  16, 32, 41, 42, 59, 77, 90, 105, 137, 150.

Comment: Those are for rectification of your sins, not for praying for someone's recovery.

Comment: First of all, you should always rectify your sins before praying for someone else ('Likutei Moharan', 282). Second, after reading the tikun you can say Mi'sheberach as to all that need.